# Dojo Ajax request to a Node server

Tags: node.js, ajax, dojo

I am trying to make an ajax request to a Node server, using the dojo library in my client. So far I can't have Node server extract the value from my Dojo request. I plan to use this value, and process it at the Node server, and return back to the client. What am I missing?

Here is my Node app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/calculate', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Calculation request received!');
    //console.log(req.body);
    //console.log(req.query);
    // Multiply the number by 2
    res.send("?");

});

app.listen(1337, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 1337');
});
```

My dojo+html

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id='calculate-button'>Calculate</button>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script>
    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(dom, on, request){
            on(dom.byId("calculate-button"), "click", function(evt){
                myValue = 2;
                request.post("http://localhost:1337/calculate", {value: myValue}).then(
                    function(response){
                        console.log("Result: " + response);
                    },
                    function(error){
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install npm `body-parser`, So that you can extract post data inside `req.body`

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

after `var app = express();`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

Add middleware to initialize it

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

After install and init, posted data will be available as `console.log(req.body)`

[**Official Doc**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)